# Is the L2 limit of a polynomial holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175405/71829). Let $D$ be the unit disk, and for each $n$ let $f_n\in L^2(D)$ be a polynomial in $z=x+iy$ with complex coefficients.  And suppose that $f_n\rightarrow f$ with respect to the $L^2(D)$ norm for some $f\in L^2(D)$.  My question is, is it necessarily true that $f$ is holomorphic?

If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?  I ask because this is true for uniform convergence.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2680166/42969: *“for a sequence of holomorphic functions on a compact set,
convergence in $L^2$ implies uniform convergence.”*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c \in D$ and $B$ is a disk around $c$ whose closure is contained in $D$ then $f_n(c)-f_m(c)$ is the average of $f_n-f_m$ over $B$. Together with Cauchy - Schwarz inequality this tells you that $\{f_n\}$ actually converges uniformly on $B$. If a sequence of holomorphic functions converges locally uniformly the limit is holomorphic. Note that $f$ is only an equivalence class of functions, so the correct statement is $f=g$ almost everywhere with $g$ holomorphic.